# Continuity of the function $F(x)=\int_0^{+\infty} f(x,t) d t$

Tags: functions, continuity

Let $f(x,t): \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function (that is any order of derivative with respect $x$ and $t$ exists).

Can we say $$F(x)=\int_0^{+\infty} f(x,t) d t$$ is continuous in $x$?

If the integral interval is finite, I believe it is continuous. But I am not sure about the above case where the integral interval is infinite. Any proof or counter-example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that continuity fails even for $f(x,t) = xt$, at $0$ for instance, the integral being $0$ at that point and diverging everywhere else.

Comment: Thanks. Then, I guess the discontinuity happens only if the integral diverges at that point.